# Using function pointers?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm not yet very familiar with these but maybe someone can shine light on this example.

Imagine I have class CFoo and it will have a function to add a handler and a function which is a function pointer.

So something like this:

```
class CFoo {

int *pointedFunc(int a, int b) = 0;

void setFunc(int *func(int a, int b))
{
    pointedFunc = func;
}
};
```

Given the above context, I want to know the proper way of doing this. I don't think I have done it properly. Also, how would I go about calling pointedFunc?

Thanks

Comment: Not "a *function* which is a function pointer", but "a *member variable* (known in OO as a *field*) which is a function pointer".

Comment: Please avoid function pointers in C++ code. Define an interface and create types that implement that interface. You can then store objects neatly without having to resort to C hocks-pockus of function pointers.

Comment: @Martin: Sometimes an interface is the right approach, sometimes templated (and duck-typed) functors, and sometimes function pointers are best.  Especially for dynamic linking, function pointers are needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now you have a member function returning `int *`, not a pointer to a function returning `int`.  A set of parenthesis would fix that.

```
int (*pointedFunc)(int a, int b);

void setFunc(int (*pfunc)(int a, int b))
{
    pointedFunc = pfunc;
}
```

Also, member variables get initialized in the constructor *ctor-initializer-list*, like

```
CFoo::CFoo() : pointedFunc(0) {}
```

not like you did.  Your `= 0` was actually a pure-specifier (and it won't work unless the member function is virtual), when you fix the pointer-return-type vs pointer-to-function issue you'll find that the compiler also complains about your attempt to initialize it.

[Using a typedef as Graeme suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835738/using-function-pointers/3835752#3835752) is the easiest and best way to keep track of function-pointer types.

Comment: It's not so much that it's only for virtual functions, as that `= 0` means something **completely different** (cue Monty Python) when it appears in a function declaration as when it appears in a data declaration.  Actually, `int (*pointedFunc)(int a, int b) = 0;` would be perfectly OK as a local variable, which can be initialized, but member variables get initialized in the constructor and not in the declaration.

Comment: While you're certainly correct about setting a function itself = 0 being a pure-specifier, I'm under the impression you can set a function *pointer* to NULL with no issues, which I believe was the original intent.

Comment: @Bryan: absolutely you can set it (the variable with function-pointer type) to NULL.  But not in the declaration of a non-static member variable.  Non-static member variables get initialized in a *ctor-initializer-list*.

Comment: Oh... I submitted my answer partly written so I could check what his class name was, I guess you saw that before I added the *ctor-initializer-list* example.

Comment: @Ben: Oh... duh. I knew that. Hah, thanks for keeping me straight.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `pointedFunc` is a member function that returns an `int *`. To make it a function pointer, you need parens around `pointedFunc`, like:

```
int (*pointedFunc)( int a, int b );
```

A typedef might make it clearer:

```
class CFoo {
    CFoo() : pointedFunc( NULL ) {}
    typedef int (*funcType)(int, int);
    funcType pointedFunc;

    void setFunc( funcType f ) {
         pointedFunc = f;
    }
};
```

To call the function, you can use either `pointedFunc( 1, 2 )` or `(*pointedFunc)(1, 2)`. I tend to use the latter to make it clear that you are going through a function pointer, but either will work.

Comment: No it's not fine, right now he has a member function named `pointedFunc` and the return type is `int*`.